# What is the expected number of ‘runs’?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We toss a fair coin n times (independently). 
Runs are consecutive tosses with the same result. For instance, the toss sequence HHHTTHTH has 5 runs while the sequence HHHHTTTT has 2 runs.

Comment: What have you tried? I would recommend some kind of recursive formula. Like $$E_n = \dfrac{1}{2}E_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}(1+E_{n-1}) = E_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}$$ The last flip either continues the previous run or it starts a new one.

Comment: Hint: You might define $X_i=1$ if the $i$th toss starts a run.  Then you could use linearity of expectation to find $E(\sum X_i)$.

Comment: @awkward i think it is will be a sigma, X can just be 1 so we could ignore it when multiplying, meaning the expectancy is just the probability when X = 1.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thats a smart suggestion, would you say just finding the generating function of that recurrence would be enough? I understand how you came to it, but proving it also seems hard

Comment: @Sam since $E_1 = 1$, the generating function is easy: $$E_n = \dfrac{n+1}{2}$$ The recurrence is proven by Linearity of Expectation, just as Graham Kemp suggests.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe something like E[n] = E[(n-1)+1] = E[n-1] + E[1] = E[n-1] + 1/2 ?

Comment: @Sam That is not quite how linearity of expectation works. It is more like, $$E[n] = E[n|\text{some conditional}] + E[n|\text{some other disjoint conditional}]$$ where the two conditionals union to cover the whole sample space. There is probably a more clear notation than that, but that is the general idea.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe what should this conditional be so that i could use the linearity of expectation?

Comment: $$E[n] = E[n|n\text{-th flip is not a new run}] + E[n|n\text{-th flip is start of new run}] = P[n\text{-th flip is same as last run}]\cdot E[n-1] + P[n\text{-th flip is different from last run}]\cdot (1+E[n-1]) = \dfrac{1}{2}E[n-1]+\dfrac{1}{2}(1+E[n-1]) = E[n-1]+\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Another way to look at it: Let $X_n$ be a random variable representing the number of runs after $n$ flips of a coin. Let $A_n$ be a random variable representing the number of runs after $n$ flips of a coin where the last flip matches the second to last flip or zero otherwise. Let $B_n$ be a random variable representing the number of runs after $n$ flips of a coin where the last flip does not match the second to last flip or zero otherwise. Then $$E[X_n] = E[A_n+B_n] = E[A_n]+E[B_n] = \dfrac{1}{2}E[n-1]+\dfrac{1}{2}(1+E[n-1])$$

Comment: Graham Kemp's suggestion to use random variable indicator functions is even easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it is 1 plus the expected count, among the remaining $n-1$ coins, that they do not show the same face as their predecessor.

The coins are fair and independent, so the probability that a particular coin doesn't show the same face as its predecessor is $1/2$.

Now use the Linearity of Expectation.

Comment: how will linearity be used in this case?

Comment: Use indicator random variables.  Let $X_i$ equal $1$ if coin $i$ shows a different face than coin $i-1$, and equal $0$ otherwise.  Then $(1+\sum_{I=2}^n X_i)$ counts the runs.  Find its expectation.